# Add parentheses to make this true

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Add parentheses to the following to make a true equation:

$10-9\times8-7\times6-5\times4-3\times2-2\times1=1$

Comment: As the OP stated in one of the deleted comments...the source of this is: http://imgur.com/a/24nJE. But one typo made the puzzle way better (at least not trivial). It's from a 4th grade math book. In case you are wondering what the other 2 problems on the image mean, I cannot make out the first one completely. But the second one says "It's Michael's birthday. He meets with 12 of his friends and each one shakes hands with each other. How many handshakes are in total?"

Comment: Are we allowed to turn a minus sign into a negative sign?  For example, turn 6-5*4 into 6(-5*4)?

Comment: Also, one might turn `10...` into `1(0...`

Comment: I found another online source of the original document that shows the entire page. The first problem reads, in full, "Pe terenul de joacă sunt de 5 ori mai multe fete decât băieți. Câți copii sunt pe teren?" which Google translate tells me is Romanian for "On the playground there are 5 times more girls than boys. How many children are on the field?", which is also unanswerable.

Comment: @Mat No, because all mathematical signs are `*` or `-`. In `6(-5*4)` you are adding new `*` sign between `6` and the `(` which is obviously not allowed. We need to add only brackets.

Comment: [Related Programming Puzzles & Code Golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121372/34718)

Answer (score 23):

> No matter how you place the parentheses, the result will never be 1, because it is always even.

How I found the solution:

> Let's take a look at the equation mod 2:
>  $0+1\times0+1\times0+1\times0+1\times0+0\times1=1$
>  We start with $0\times1=1$ which is clearly false. Then either $1\times$ or $0+$ is added to the left of the equation. Both of these will never modify the expression to their right, no matter when they are executed.
>  This means we can continue this chain as often as we like and the result will always stay even.

Comment: The proof fails, since overlooks things like `(0+0)*1`. Also more exotic placements.

Comment: Agreed that the proof is not nearly rigorous enough. But I believe the conclusion holds, even if the proof is sketchy.

Comment: @Hurkyl I think the proof works fine, just badly explained. A `0+` or `1*` does not change the parity of the term/factor on the right, regardless of whether that term/factor is a bracketed expression or a single number. There cannot be a bracket between the two characters of `0+` or `1*`. However the brackets are located, you can remove occurrences of `0+` or `1*` since they don't matter, and remove unnecessary brackets, and you will end up with `0*1`, the last term of the unbracketed expression. e.g. `(0+0)*1 = (0)*1 = 0*1`. This version of the proof is in opposite direction to the above.

Comment: Addendum: The proof does not allow for the loopholes that Mat and Hurkyl pointed out in comments on the main post: inserting a bracket between a number and a minus sign (e.g turning `6-5*4` into `6(-5*4)` ) or in between digits (i.e. turning `10...` into `1(0...` ).

Comment: The proof does assume that the signs represent the binary operations subtraction and multiplication and that the only thing that changes is the order in which they are executed. For those assumptions the proof works even if I might have explained it badly.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Splitting the digits of 10 just turns the 10- to a 1*0- for which the proof still holds. The other one switches a 0-1*0 to a 0*1*0 which can indeed change parity, but only from odd to even. So even without those restrictions, there won't be any solution.

Comment: Actually, I believe the modulo operator distributed among addition and multiplication so the transformation is valid.

Answer (score 8):

To take things from a literal computational perspective:

> $10-9\times8-7\times6-5\times4-3\times2-2\times(1=1)$
>  Because $(1=1) == true$ in many languages such as Wolfram Alpha
>  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10-9*8-7*6-5*4-3*2-2*(1%3D1)

Important to note that truthy values can be very lenient:

> So $-2 \times true - 130$ still evaluates to $true$ (in fact any value $\ne 0$ would) 
>  So this is "True" in the computational sense rather than the mathematical sense

Comment: An interesting idea - but `=` != `==`

Comment: Yeah, as a programmer that was annoying me, but many languages of a symbolic processing / computational algebra nature do indeed interpret = as == (hence the wolfram alpha reference) @shadow, even though it makes my head hurt hahah

Comment: SQL does it too :(

Answer (score 7):

Since w l's proof doesn't really work, I used a simple python program to iterate through all possible placements, and the answer is:

> There is no solution

And the program is a simple recursion:

```
import itertools

def recurse(part):
    res = set()
    for i in range(1, len(part), 2):
        left = part[:i]
        right = part[i + 1:]
        left = recurse(left) if len(left) > 1 else left
        right = recurse(right) if len(right) > 1 else right
        for x, y in itertools.product(left, right):
            res.add(x - y if part[i] == '-' else x * y)
    return res

1 in recurse([10, '-', 9, '*', 8, '-', 7, '*', 6, '-', 5, '*', 4, '-', 3, '*', 2, '-', 2, '*', 1])
```

To verify that it works without the typo, you can run:

```
1 in recurse([10, '-', 9, '*', 8, '-', 7, '*', 6, '-', 5, '*', 4, '-', 3, '*', 2, '-', 1])
```

Comment: What exactly does not work in my proof? The explanation might not be perfect, but the basic idea works. Your program could also easily verify that all results are even.

Comment: Does your program include multiple encapsulation? Something in the vein of ((8-7)*6-5)*4? Having multiple brackets in a row, differently put?

Comment: @WeckarE. Yes it includes all possible placements. You can check that the # of solutions if not using a set are the Catalan numbers.

Comment: @wl I guess you're right it could be made to work using mod 2 and some argument.

Answer (score 6):

That's the best I have so far.

> Since there is no base specified, until I find an other solution, I'm going to use the loophole of computing everything in base 11.
>  $10-(9\times8-7\times6-5\times4-3\times(2-2\times1))_{11}$ =
>  $11-(9\times8-7\times6-5\times4-3\times(2-2\times1))_{10}$ =
>  $11 - (72 - 42 - 20 - 0) $ =
>  $11 - 10 = 1$

Comment: I think you forgot to switch base

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering if the transformation of

> $10-9\times8-7\times6-5\times4-3\times2-2\times1 = 1$
> into
>  $10-9\times8-7\times6-5\times4-3\times2-2\times1 - 1 = 0$ is acceptable

Because if so, the answer could be

> $1(0(-9\times8-7\times6-5\times4-3\times2-2\times1)(-1)) = 0$

Answer (score 3):

Easy, this is true for

> $x=\frac9{142}$, without any parentheses at all.

Explanation:

> $10−9\times8−7\times6−5\times4−3\times2−2\times1=1$ 
>  
> is the same as $10 - 9x8 - 7x6-5x4-3x2-2x1 = 1$
>  
> which is the same as $10 - 142x = 1$,
>  
> which is true for $x = 9/142$.
>  See it on [Wolfram Alpha!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%20-%209%20*%20x%20*%208%20-%207%20*%20x%20*%206%20-%205%20*%20x%20*%204%20-%203%20*%20x%20*%202%20-%202%20*%20x%20*%201%20%3D%201)

Of course,

> this only works if you treat the $\times$ sign as an actual $x$, and not as a multiplication...

Comment: How can you put a variable *x* anywhere in the equation and not everywhere? Basically, you are replacing * with * x *

Comment: The trick is that I am treating the symbol x not as a multiplication sign, but as a variable, which itself is multiplied to the surrounding numbers.

Comment: But, you still have the multiplication sign right? So, you are not replacing multiplication, but adding a variable right?

Comment: I can see why this is misleading. @GentlePurpleRain edited my answer, so that now the main point is lost. I will revert it.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. But still, not sure if it's allowed. But nice :)

Comment: I made another edit, which I think makes it more clear.  If you don't like it, feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2):

> I found all `16 797` possible solutions, but none of them are equal to 1.

Since `pastebin` doesn't allowed me to add all answers in one bin, I had to split them in two bins.

The first 8000 - [https://pastebin.com/YE0FqQpm](https://pastebin.com/GuVvv1QF)

The rest 8797 - https://pastebin.com/GuVvv1QF

Answer (score 0):

I'll give another solution, related to the answer given by Marcus

> Using base 15.
>  $(10-(9\times8-7\times6-(5\times4-3\times2)-2\times1))_{15}$ =
>  $(10-(4\text{C}-2\text{C}-(15-6)-2))_{15}$ =
>  $(10-(20-\text{E}-2))_{15}$ =
>  $(10-(11 - 2))_{15}$ =
>  $(10-\text{E})_{15}$ =
>  $1_{15}$

Answer (score 0):

1 (0-9×8-7×6-5×4-3×(2-2))×1=1

Never specified whether I can break up numbers

Comment: Your parentheses are not balanced and the result is 0, not 1.

Comment: Fixed it (I think I did)

Comment: Your latest version amounts to  "1 * (0-9*8-7*6-5*4-3*(2-2)) * 1" which equals $-134$.  Are you actually evaluating the answers you're posting?

Comment: I am not good at this

Comment: If you're not sure what you are doing, you don't *have* to leave a new answer.

Answer (score -1):

After focusing a while, I think I have found the answer.

 According to me the parenthesis would be added in following sequence:

> (10-9) * (8-7) * (6-5) * (4-3) * (2-1)=1
>   
> As
>   
>  1) 10-9=1:- (1) * (8-7) * (6-5) * (4-3) * (2-1)=1
>   
>  2) 8-7=1:- (1) * (1) * (6-5) * (4-3) * (2-1)=1
>   
>  3) 6-5=1:- (1) * (1) * (1) * (4-3) * (2-1)=1
>   
>  4) 4-3=1:- (1) * (1) * (1) * (1) * (2-1)=1
>   
>  5) 2-1=1:- (1) * (1) * (1) * (1) * (1)=1

Hence,

> 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1=1

Comment: There are two 2s in the original problem, not just one.

Comment: Oops i didn't noticed that thanx @JaapScherphuis for letting me know

Answer (score -4):

It would look something like the following (see explanation because the last couple of steps depend on pen and paper)

> ([(10-9*8-7*6-5*4-3)*(2-2)]) * (1)=1

Reasoning:

> 1) Put a parenthesis around (2-2) so it becomes zero and zeros out everything to it's left.
>
>   2) So you have this without the final pairs of parenthesis:
>   0*1=1
>
>   3) Draw the final pairs of parentheses so they intersect with the multiplication sign's bottom four points, leaving a straight line
>   (0)*(1) = 1
>
>   4) Which, without the parentheses, is
>   0 | 1 = 1
>
>   5) Since "|" is the bitwise OR and 1 normally represents TRUE, this is a true expression

Comment: Can you explain the "devolves to" part?

Comment: @Deusovi when the parentheses drop away, that's what you've got left.